# How can I deploy with Ant and run tests but ignore code coverage?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, ant

My team sometimes has a release process that requires deploying multiple packages in stages. We want to make sure that the system remains stable at the end of each of these deployments by running a few sanity tests, but we don't care about the code coverage until we deploy the last package.

Is there a way to run an `<sf:deploy>` target that runs a few test classes (and fails if those tests fail), but *does not fail* if code coverage is not reached for the deployed classes?

Comment: have you tried run specific test though you can't bypass overall code coverage, you need overall code coverage to 75%

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Sadly, bypassing the code coverage check is exactly what I need.
I tried deploying and running the tests class separately and that worked - because the test class is the only one that's checked for coverage and of course it runs completely. But I need this to happen in the same deploy so that I can roll back the other files if the tests fail.

Answer (score 2):

By default, no tests are run in a deployment to a non-production organization, such as a sandbox or a Developer Edition organization.

To specify tests to run in your development environment, set a testLevel deployment option. For example, to run local tests in a deployment and to exclude managed package tests, add the **testLevel="RunLocalTests"** parameter to the deploy target.

```
<target name="deployCode">
<sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}"
sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
deployroot="codepkg" testLevel="RunLocalTests">
</sf:deploy>
</target>
```

**Running a Subset of Tests in a Deployment**

If the code coverage of an Apex component in the deployment is less than 75%, the deployment fails. If one of the specified tests fails, the deployment also fails. We recommend that you test your deployment in sandbox first to ensure that the specified tests cover each component sufficiently. Even if your organization’s overall code coverage is 75% or more, the individual coverage of the Apex components being deployed can be less. If the code coverage requirement isn’t met, write more tests and include them in the deployment.
To run a subset of tests, add the **testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests"** parameter to the deploy target. Specify each test class to run for a deploy target in a   child element within the sf:deploy element. Add the test class name within the   tags. Add as many runTest tags as you need, one for each test class.

```
<target name="deployCode">
<sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}"
sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
deployroot="codepkg" testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests">
<runTest>TestClass1</runTest>
<runTest>TestClass2</runTest>
<runTest>TestClass3</runTest>
</sf:deploy>
</target>
```

Refer: [Force.com Migration Tool Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Santanu, but this is part of the official documentation and I had already gone through that. In our case, we need to have tests make the deployment fail but code coverage NOT make the deployment fail, which the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_run_specific_tests.htm) does not mention.

Comment: Perform Run local test

Comment: Using runLocalTests would run **all** local tests (which would take 1+ hours), but we need to run only **a few selected** of our test classes (that we know would run in a couple minutes).

Comment: if you need to run few selected classes then RunSpecifiedTests. Now here Salesforce expects each class must have 75% coverage

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution. I'd like to perform a deployment and execute all tests with a flag to opt out of collecting code coverage.
I'm aware that we can do it manually as we can see on Salesforce Summer ’18 Release Notes. (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_opt_out_code_coverage.htm). Seems that this option isn't available yet, is it?

Comment: @PabloFischer you can post as separate question

Comment: Thanks @SantanuBoral! I thought my comment was related to this topic and I was trying to avoid a duplicate question. Anyway, I followed your suggestion and I created another question to address that. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/230347/perform-a-deployment-and-execute-all-tests-with-a-flag-to-opt-out-of-collecting

Answer (score 1):

You can opt out code coverage by

```
Developer Console > Test > New Run > Settings > Tick "Skip Code Coverage"
```

[image: Skip Code Coverage]

Source: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_opt_out_code_coverage.htm.