# Perform a deployment and execute all tests with a flag to opt out of collecting code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I'd like to perform a deployment and execute all tests with a flag to opt out of collecting code coverage.

The goal is to speed up Apex test execution. I'm aware that we can do it manually by executing the steps provided through the Salesforce Summer ’18 Release Notes.

Source: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_opt_out_code_coverage.htm.

Seems that this option isn't available yet, is it?

PS: Test coverage is really important, but in my case, I have multiple builds running in parallel and I'd like to turn it off for some of them.

Comment: This option is available and I just did ANT deployment and it worked!

Comment: Thanks @compski! Would you mind sharing how you've implemented that. I've double checked the documentation, but I could not find it. How did you set the ant task to opt out of collecting code coverage?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy.htm

Comment: Check out my answer here which includes screenshot https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/241113/38191

Comment: Thanks @compski, the solution you posted on the link works for sure and seems to be exactly the same one available on Summer 18 release link (source). Please notice that I've inserted comments on this topic too and SantanuBora recommend me to create a separate post, (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207376/how-can-i-deploy-with-ant-and-run-tests-but-ignore-code-coverage/241113#241113)