# Schedulable single email apex class low coverage when deployed to production

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, scheduled-apex, failing-tests, singleemailmessage

I have a schedulable email apex class that sends email to sales rep with opportunities with awaiting approval as stage. This partial apex class below is 100% covered in production, however when I deploy to production I only get 53% code coverage and this is even without the actual sendemail method in it. Can anyone help me with the test class for this?

```
global class ProductionAwaitingEmail Implements Schedulable 
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
    {
        List<Production__c> prod = [Select Id, Name, Account__r.Account_Owner__c, Sales_Rep__c, Opportunity_Name__r.Name, Owner.Email from Production__c where 
                                    Status__c  = 'ACT Awaiting Customer Approval' AND RecordType.Name = 'ACT Production'];

                                    Map<String, List<Production__c>> userMap = new Map<String, List<Production__c>>();
                                    List<User> userList = [Select Id, Name, Email from User];
                            
                            
                                    for( User u : userList ){
                                        for(Production__c pr :  prod) {  
                                            if(u.Name == pr.Sales_Rep__c){
                                                if(!userMap.containsKey(u.email)){
                                                     userMap.put(u.email, new List<Production__c>());
                                                    }
                                                    userMap.get(u.email).add(pr);
                                            }  
                                        }
                                    }
                            
                                    for( String u : userMap.keySet()){
                                        List<String> p = new List<String>();
                                        String firstName = userMap.get(u)[0].Sales_Rep__c.split(' ')[0];
                                        //send email
                                        }
    }           
}
```

}

Herer is my test class

```
    @isTest
public class ProductionAwaitingEmailTest{
    @isTest
    public static  void startTest(){
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='system administrator'];
         
        User us = new User(Alias='Admin',Email='test@gamil.com',FirstName='Admin', LastName='Testing',Username='standardsalesforceadmin00@amindustrial.com',LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',LocaleSidKey='en_US',ProfileId = p.Id, 
           TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8');
           insert us;

        Opportunity Opp=new Opportunity();
        Opp.Name='Demo Opportunity';
        Opp.StageName='Qualification';
        Opp.CloseDate=system.today();
        insert Opp;
        
        Production__c Prds=new Production__c();
        Prds.Opportunity_Name__c=Opp.id;
        Prds.Status__c='ACT Awaiting Customer Approval';
        Prds.Sales_Rep__c ='Admin Testing';
        insert Prds;

        String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 15 3 ? 2027';
    
        Test.startTest();
        String jobId = System.schedule('Test my class',
                        CRON_EXP, 
                        new ProductionAwaitingEmail());

                        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, 
                        NextFireTime
                        FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId];


        Test.stopTest();
    }      
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please [edit] your post to show which specific lines you are struggling to cover. See [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244794/how-do-i-increase-my-code-coverage-or-why-cant-i-cover-these-lines) for our standard resources on code coverage.

Comment: In sandbox this code is 100% covered, however in production it says 53% covered and does not show which lines are not covered. What I posted above is the actual code ( no logic for email send and still getting 53%). So I guess the lines are not covered are the for loops.

Comment: You need to view the code coverage in Developer Console or through the `sfdx` CLI to get enough information to continue working on this issue. Make sure your test also _passes_ in production.

Comment: When trying to deploy this apex class to production it only says "Your code coverage is 53%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.". It does not show me what lines are not covered.

This apex class is 100% covered in sandbox.

Comment: note that your test does nothing useful -- you don't do any asserts to see that the schedulable `execute()` did what you expect. That said, your issue is most likely that you are running all tests in PROD and they collectively fall below 75% code coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a Subset of Tests in a Deployment

If the code coverage of an Apex component in the deployment is less than 75%, the deployment fails. If one of the specified tests fails, the deployment also fails. We recommend that you test your deployment in sandbox first to ensure that the specified tests cover each component sufficiently. Even if your organization’s overall code coverage is 75% or more, the individual coverage of the Apex components being deployed can be less. If the code coverage requirement isn’t met, write more tests and include them in the deployment. To run a subset of tests, add the testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests" parameter to the deploy target. Specify each test class to run for a deploy target in a child element within the sf:deploy element. Add the test class name within the tags. Add as many runTest tags as you need, one for each test class.

TestClass1
TestClass2
TestClass3

[How can I deploy with Ant and run tests but ignore code coverage?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207376/how-can-i-deploy-with-ant-and-run-tests-but-ignore-code-coverage)